# Is there a way to keep whitespace in django admin __unicode__ strings?

Tags: html, django, unicode, admin, whitespace

In order to uniquely identify my model records in the django admin interface, I am joining the unicode of several fields in sequence. These become the links to select individual records to edit.

To improve readability I'd like to display them to appear as columns. So rather than...

```
Fred Flintstone 1985-06-11
Jim Bean 1999-03-02
Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart 1756-01-27
```

I want

```
Fred Flintstone             1985-06-11
Jim Bean                    1999-03-02
Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart     1756-01-27
```

If I format my __unicode__ function return to have extra whitespace, Django will include it in the html but the browser collapses the whitespace. Is there a simple way to change the layout of these line items while keeping the admin? Maybe by somehow getting "pre" tags to be output - I'm not an html expert so I suspect that may not be legal inside the "a href", but maybe the text could be appended after the link, with a fixed link at the front something like

```
<a href="/blah/blah/1/">Select</a><pre>Fred Flintstone             1985-06-11</pre>
<a href="/blah/blah/2/">Select</a><pre>Jim Bean                    1999-03-02</pre>
```

Apologies if that's bad html but hopefully you understand what I'm saying.
I realise I could do a template and my own view but the admin almost does what I need for a lot of the application apart from this formatting issue, and there will be quite a lot of different pages like this.

Answer (score 1):

You want this instead: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display

Basically, you specify how to list your model items and this is used instead of calling `__unicode__` on your model.